# Inheritance Database in Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm following this course [MVC with Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

The class diagram in this course is something like this: [Class Diagram image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6ex0.png)

In inheritance part [Inheritance Part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/inheritance?view=aspnetcore-5.0) , they create a new table `Person` to store all the data for 2 models `Student` and `Instructor` in Entity Framework. And also drop 2 tables `Student` and `Instructor` in the database.

Now, there are 3 models in Entity Framework: `Person`, `Student`, `Instructor`

I try to get data into `Student` and `Instructor` models without loading `Person` by

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("Person");
```

and I get this message:

[image: Invalid Operation]

Code:

```
public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
public DbSet<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
private DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Person");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Instructor>().ToTable("Person");
}
```

**Questions**

**1.** Does it mean all the data must be get into Entity Framework?

**2.** In situation, for sensitive data is there any kind of pattern to make inheritance database?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using the "old", classic Entity Framework (v6.x) on .NET Core - or are you using the Entity Framework **Core** version? Please be clear - your question and tags are not very clear in that regard.

Comment: my bad, thanks for your new edition.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, there are 3 models in Entity Framework: Person, Student, Instructor

If you don't have a use case that requires it, don't make Person an Entity.  Just Student and Instructor.  Then you won't have any inheritance in the database.